# Not seeing how to disable typing auto-suggest drop-down in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This seemed to have happened with a recent update, but when I start typing anything that could have a suggestion, it drops down a box showing potential completion suggestions; it obscures code and is distracting, and I only want it to happen when I manually activate it, like with Ctrl+Space.

However, I'm not finding the option to stop it from happening while typing... the best I can find is in File > Preferences > Settings > Editor: Quick Suggestions (Controls whether suggestions should automatically show up while typing.), which just has a link to "Edit in settings.json", when I click that I get these options:

```
{
    "editor.hover": false,
    "editor.wordBasedCompletion": true,
    "editor.parameterHints": false,
    "editor.parameterHints.cycle": true,
    "editor.hover.delay": 3000,
    "editor.hover.sticky": false,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "debug.node.autoAttach": "on",
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
}
```

Everything looks correct there... I change a few and it doesn't fix it. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to click or whatever to disable this annoying feature.

Comment: Not all the settings are listed in the settings.json. When you click on "_Edit in settings.json_", it is telling you that you can edit the default values, which for Quick Suggestions are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using 1.36.1 
I think the setting you are looking for is

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false, 
    }
```

Please add it in settings.json

Comment: That doesn't have a GUI setting?

Comment: I don't think so. As you said it in your question : just has a link to "Edit in settings.json"; I can see the same.